# WiFi Disconnecting (Special Issue)

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-4, vpn

I could not afford my Internet this month, it has happened before, but I am turning it back on next week.

Anyways, so on my PC (which is connected to the Internet via Ethernet), the Internet works but blocks websites obviously since I didn't pay the bill, but if I use SSH tunneling, or use a VPN I can reroute the web traffic and visit any website I want.

On my laptop, which uses WiFi, I can do the exact same thing...

Now on my Android device (Galaxy S4), when connecting it says "Sign In Required" or something, and when I click Chrome to sign in, it just goes to Google and stuff, and every other site is blocked as expected. I can use a VPN like Betternet to unlock the other sites like I would on my computer. However, the WiFi on my Android disconnects every 3 or 4 minutes, whether I use a VPN or not, and I am not sure why this happens exclusively to my Android, and not any other device such as my laptop.

Any ideas on what is happening? Any router changes I can do, any Android changes I can do?